# (Python) Trying to parse with beautifulsoup on a webpage that updates after its initial load

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For example, if you go here: https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/herters-hunting-rifle-ammo/

you'll notice on the first load, it'll show everything in stock. Then, the page will update again and show all the things which are out of stock.

Is there any way to use beautifulsoup to account for this? I'm starting to think I'm going to need to use a different strategy to pull the updated HTML code.

As it stands, my code returns nothing because there is no "out of stock" text in the code that beautifulsoup pulls.

```
content_wrapper = soup.find('div', class_='col2 gridCell StoreAvail editable anchored', id='StoreAvail_7')
cheese = content_wrapper.find('div', class_='sublist instore_inventory_section nodisplay',
                              id='WC_InStore_Inventory_Section_3074457345618960372')

print(cheese)
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You probably want to use Selemium for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data about stock info is loaded from different URL. You can use this example to print stock status, quantity etc.:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0', 'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Referer': 'https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/herters-hunting-rifle-ammo/'}

url = 'https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/herters-hunting-rifle-ammo/'
in_stock_url = 'https://www.basspro.com/shop/BPSGetOnlineInventoryStatusByIDView'

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

productId = soup.select_one('meta[name="pageId"]')['content']
storeId = re.search(r'"storeId"\s*:\s*\'([\d]+)\'', html_text).group(1)
catalogId = re.search(r'"catalogId"\s*:\s*\'([\d]+)\'', html_text).group(1)

# sometimes, the server returns error page, so repeat the loading untill success:
while True:
    try:
        json_txt = requests.post(in_stock_url, headers=headers, data={'productId': productId, 'storeId': storeId, 'catalogId': catalogId}).text
        data = json.loads( re.search(r'/\*(.*)\*/', json_txt, flags=re.S).group(1) )
        break
    except:
        pass

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for k in data['onlineInventory']:
    d = soup.select_one('#WC_Sku_List_Row_Content_' + k)
    if d:
        print(d.select_one('.CartridgeorGauge').get_text(strip=True))
        print(d.select_one('.ModelNumber').get_text(strip=True))
        print(data['onlineInventory'][k]['altText'])
        print(data['onlineInventory'][k]['quantity'])
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
.30-30 Winchester
HRT3030A
In-Stock
158
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.30-06 Springfield
HRT3006C
In-Stock
16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.308 Winchester
HRT308D
Out of Stock
0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.300 AAC Blackout
HRT300BLK
Out of Stock
0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.22-250 Remington
HRT22250A
In-Stock
192
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.223 Remington
HRT223B
Out of Stock
0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.223 Remington
HRT223150
Out of Stock
32
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Wow. How did you figure out the other URL for the inventory? Did you like search for "inventory" or something in the network menu? You are a wizard man.

Comment: @DanJones I openet Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab and watched, where the page is making requests. Sometimes yeah, it's _detective_ work...

Answer (score 1):

The site you're crawling is not server-side-rendered but rendered on the client side, possibly with some Javascript Library/Framework like React.js or Angular.

You need to use a headless browser if you like to scrape a website like this. The most popular headless browser is [Puppeteer and there is a port for Python](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) as well.

Puppeteer spins up a real chromium instance and thus parses/renders all the Javascript driven content on the site. Obviously it takes a little longer.

Comment: That is awesome. I had no idea this was a thing! Also, how did you know it was a client-side rendered webpage? Just by the way it loaded?

Comment: Honestly, I just assumed so from the description of your problem.