# Why is the html imported through beautifulsoup and the actual html different?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm making a program that scrapes the results for a search term in stackoverflow.

I wrote the code to get the maximum page for some result.

I need to know the maximum page for scraping, but the html structure viewed through the developer tool and the html information obtained through beautifulsoup are different.

url : https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vue

below is information about the div tag whose class name is s-paginatino through developer tools.
[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vue"
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

[image]
To get this, write the code and output the result of soup to find s-pagination. The result is as follows.

The maximum number of pages displayed when entering the url is 2, but the result obtained through beautifulsoup is 43, so I cannot get the result I want. When you run the program, it does not **scrape** up to 2 pages related to vue, but also **scrapes** jobs with irrelevant keywords.

I couldn't figure out where the problem occurred, so I asked a question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the page is client side rendered, so you have to use a headless browser to visit the site and get the fully rendered version. Check out this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652771/python-trying-to-parse-with-beautifulsoup-on-a-webpage-that-updates-after-its/63652821#63652821

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header. Without it, I receive value 43 too.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vue'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('.s-pagination a')['title'])
```

Prints:

```
page 1 of 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's been a long time ago, but I finally solved it. Thank you very much. Have a nice day